# adding angular attributes to child nodes with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent-child

I have this snipet

```
<div id="colors">
    <div id="red" >Red</div>
    <div id="green" >Green</div>
    <div id="blue" >Blue</div>
    <div id="purple" >Purple</div>
    <div id="gray" >Dark Slate Gray</div>
    <div id="olive" >Olive</div>
</div>
```

and I would like to add `angular.js` attributes to each child, to make it "angular compatible". Now, I know I have to do something like

```
for (i in document.getElementById("colors").childNodes.length){
    document.getElementById("colors").childNodes[i];
}
```

But I dont know how to do the final part, actually add the new attribute, something like

```
document.getElementById("colors").childNodes[i].attribute('data:ng-hide', 'hidden');
```

Thanks

UPDATE

I am a `angular.js` newbie

This is the whole code

html file

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sockModule.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="myProductDetailCtrl">

    <button ng-click="showHideColors()" type="button">
        {{isHidden ? 'Show Available Colors' : 'Hide Available Colors'}}
    </button>

    <div id="red" ng-hide="isHidden">Red</div>
    <div id="green" ng-hide="isHidden">Green</div>
    <div id="blue" ng-hide="isHidden">Blue</div>
    <div id="purple" ng-hide="isHidden">Purple</div>
    <div id="gray" ng-hide="isHidden">Dark Slate Gray</div>
    <div id="olive" ng-hide="isHidden">Olive</div>

</body>
```

and the `sockModule.js` file

```
var sockModule = angular.module('sockModule', []);

sockModule.controller('myProductDetailCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.isHidden = true;
        $scope.showHideColors = function () {
            $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;//
        }
    }
);
```

What I want to do is replace the repeating `ng-hide="isHidden"` here :

```
<div id="red" ng-hide="isHidden">Red</div>
<div id="green" ng-hide="isHidden">Green</div>
<div id="blue" ng-hide="isHidden">Blue</div>
<div id="purple" ng-hide="isHidden">Purple</div>
<div id="gray" ng-hide="isHidden">Dark Slate Gray</div>
<div id="olive" ng-hide="isHidden">Olive</div>
```

with something faster/smarter like:

```
    <div id="colors">
        <div id="red" >Red</div>
        <div id="green" >Green</div>
        <div id="blue" >Blue</div>
        <div id="purple" >Purple</div>
        <div id="gray" >Dark Slate Gray</div>
        <div id="olive" >Olive</div>
    </div>

document.getElementById("colors").childNodes[i].setAttribute('ng-hide','isHidden');
```

It does not matter if you use angular or javascript, but please be analytical, because I am a newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about using ng-repeat?  Something like:

```
<div id="color.id" ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-hide="color.hide">{{ color.name }}</div>
```

And your model would look something like:

```
$scope.colors = [
            { id: 'red', name: 'Red', hide: true },
            { id: 'green', name: 'Green', hide: true },
            ...
        ];
```

It just depends on what you mean by making it "angular compatible".  If you're using the framework, then why not completely leverage its MVC pattern?

Comment: Making it "angular compatible" means I want to inject some angular attributes to an older code, so I can manipulate it with angular. Its a term I made up. Frankly I dont get what to do. I am angular newbie and you lost me when you said about `scope`. Check my OP update

Comment: Angular is a pretty large, comprehensive framework.  I don't know how practical it is to integrate into an older project and just some of the functionality.  In that case, you might want to use something more light-weight.  If you want to learn more about scopes, I would check out the documentation for angular controllers: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 0):

This will work (and it's simple)

```
    var colors = document.getElementById("colors").children;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(colors,function (color, i, a) {
        color.setAttribute('data:ng-hide', 'hidden');

    })
```

Comment: Where should I inject this snippet? After the whole `html` is loaded? It does not work

Comment: @slevin - this would only work after the page is loaded (with these elements).  I'm not an angular.js person - so I don't know if it would produce the effect you need, but it does add the attributes to the html elements.